# Как запустить запрос после авторизации Okhttp?

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava, okhttp

```
 public static OkHttpClient initXToken(){
        OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient= new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor=new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        okHttpClient
            .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                Log.e("ApiRequest", "initXToken= " + "Intetrceptor");
                Request.Builder builder=chain.request().newBuilder();
                builder.addHeader("X-API-Key", new SharedPrefHelper().getAccessToken());
                return chain.proceed(builder.build());
            })
            .authenticator((route, response) -> {
                Log.e("ApiRequest", "initXToken= " + "AUTH");
                if (response.code()==401) {
                    Log.e("ApiRequest", "initXToken= " + "AUTH ACCESS_TOKEN");
                    ApiRequest.refreshToken(new SharedPrefHelper().getRefreshToken())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe(responseBody -> {
                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(responseBody.string());
                            String str=jsonObject.getString("access_token");
                            new SharedPrefHelper().setAccessToken(str);
                        },Throwable::printStackTrace).isDisposed();
                    return null;
                }
                return response.request();
            });
        return okHttpClient.build();
    }
```

Почему после метода authenticator, текущий запрос, не вызывается еще раз? повторно. В итоге у меня запрос не проходит, так как я по факту прошел авторизацию, но мне надо заново нажать на кнопку которая делает интернет запрос.

Comment: Вы не пересоздаете запрос. надо не `response.request()` возвращать, а `response.request().newBuilder().build();` См [здесь](https://github.com/AndroidArchitecture/AndroidArchitectureBook/blob/master/cases/auth/Auth_article.md)
И судя по всему токен вы получаете асинхронно. вызов должен быть синхронным.